# Logistic maps in nonlinear discrete dynamical systems

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

Let T be the function T : [0, 1] → [0, 1] defined by

$$
\  
T(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{$\frac{3}{2}x$} &\quad\text{0}\le{x}<\frac{1}{2}\\
       \text{$\frac{3}{2}$(1-x)} &\quad\text{$\frac{1}{2}$}\le{x}\le{1} \\
     \end{cases}
\
$$

How would you sketch the graphs of T(x), T^2(x), and T^3(x). How many points are there of
periods one, two, and three, respectively?

Comment: For the 1st question, I'd let a graphing calculator do the work for me. For the second question, do you know the meaning of the terms "period one", "period two", and "period three"?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont own a graphing calculator.

Comment: You can probably find a website that acts as one, or an application to download that acts as one. Mac computers come with something called Grapher. But do you know what, say, "period three" means?

Comment: You still haven't told me whether you know what "period three" means. How are we going to get anywhere, if you don't meet me halfway?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply been very busy. I don't know what it means by periods. We were just given this without any notes on the content

Comment: OK. Given a number $a$, you can calculate $T(a),T(T(a)),T(T(T(a)))$, and so on. $T^2(a)$ is just an abbreviation for $T(T(a))$, $T^3(a)$ is an abbreviation for $T(T(T(a)))$, and so on. Now it may, or may not, happen that when you calculate this sequence of numbers, somewhere along the way you get back the number $a$ you started with. If that happens, $a$ is called *periodic*. If the first time it happens is at $k$, that is, if $T^k(a)=a$ but $T^j(a)\ne a$ for all $j<k$, then we say $a$ is a point of period $k$. So, can you work the problem now?

Comment: If you're too busy to engage, then I'm too busy to help.

Comment: Sorry i have been so busy with work. I work like 60 hours a week hope u can understand

Comment: Also that was helpful thnx